# RGB to HSV conversion

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm very new to Android and Opencv, I would like to convert some rgb image to hsv and I know I can use

```
 Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mat1, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
```

But how do I create the "mat" in android ?

In Java I used:

```
 byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
 Mat mat = new Mat(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
  mat.put(0, 0, data);
```

In Android I already got this:

```
mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pic1);             
mPhotoWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();
mPhotoHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

`b` is your `Bitmap` image.

```
Mat tmp = new Mat (b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
Utils.bitmapToMat(b, tmp);
Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

// back to Bitmap
Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, b);
```